# iPhone maximum capacity

Tags: iphone

My iPhone app will download a large amount of data from a remote server. What is the maximum amount of data that an iPhone application can store? If you try to store too much data, what happens?

Comment: Each IPHONE application ownes it's sole SandBox. Whether the SandBox can be unlimitedly expanded until IPHONE's disk be full up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like a computer, iPhone has RAM and hard disk space. The disk space is advertised on the box (8GB, 16GB, or 32GB). Apple does not advertise the amount of RAM, but the iPhone and iPhone 3G have 128MB and the 3GS has 256MB.

If you fill up memory, your app will receive a Memory Warning notification. If you don't free up enough memory, your app will be terminated.

If you fill up the disk, your app will probably receive disk full errors when you try to write more data.

Answer (score 2):

See [this](http://gamesfromwithin.com/whered-that-memory-go) excellent article on memory on the iPhone.

Answer (score -1):

When you first buy an iPhone it will say 8GB, 16GB, 32 GB, or 64 GB on the package. Usually they use 3 GB for something that I don't really know what for. My iPhone 4S has 64 GB on the package but on the usage settings it says that I have 62 GB still a lot but I think that apple uses some GB for some kind of settings. **I Hope this Helped :)**

Comment: This is not what the asker is looking for: the OP wants to know how much storage a *single application* can use; your answer refers to the storage capacity of the entire device.